# Use variable from post method in php file

Tags: php, post

I currently have 2 files:

- movie.php
- deletemovie.php

the movie.php will have a javascript function `deletemovie(movietitle)`.

The function is triggered when an item is clicked.

```
<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick = deletemovie('{$movie['title']}')>X</button>
```

and the `deletemovie(movietitle)` is :

```
function deletemovie(movietitle){
    console.log(movietitle);
    $.post("deletemovie.php", movietitle, "json");
  }
```

My question is, when I am handling the post data in deletemovie.php,

```
$title = $_POST[movietitle];
foreach ($movies as $movie){
    if ($movie['title'] == movietitle) {
        unset($movie['title']);
    } 
}
```

should I write like this? 
I think `$title = $_POST[movietitle];` is somehow wrong.

Any suggestion?

---

my current code is :

> movie.php

```
function deletemovie(movietitle){
  console.log(movietitle);
  $.post("deletemovie.php", movietitle, "json");
}
```

> deletemovie.php

```
foreach ($movies as $movie){
if ($movie['title'] == $_POST['movietitle']) {
    unset($movie['title']);
}
}
```

i think the unset() isn't wrong? 
But the problem still not yet solved.

---

the movie.json:

```
{
    "abc": {
        "title": "abc",
        "director": "ddd",
        "rating": "5",
        "subtitle": "Yes",
        "genre": "I",
        "category": "I",
        "release": "2018-05-03",
        "end": "2018-05-09",
        "link": "das",
        "synopsis": "dasdas"
    },
    "afs": {
        "title": "afs",
        "director": "fasf",
        "rating": "5",
        "subtitle": "Yes",
        "genre": "I",
        "category": "I",
        "release": "2018-05-09",
        "end": "2018-05-10",
        "link": "fsa",
        "synopsis": "fs"
    }
}
```

Comment: as a recommendation - don't use inline js / css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code

Answer (score 2):

Did you try putting "movietitle" in apostrophes?

```
$title = $_POST['movietitle'];
```

Otherwise php will probably interpret `movietitle` as an unknown constant and not find anything.

Also, this line looks rather wrong:

```
if ($movie['title'] == movietitle)
```

You probably want:

```
if ($movie['title'] == $_POST['movietitle'])
```

Comment: I have updated the question by using your code... but not yet solved. thanks a lot.

Comment: I am afraid I am not familiar with the JQuery part. There are 2 things I'd try to check for.  
1: Is the post variable actually being set properly? You could try adding something like  
`if(isset($_POST['movietitle'])){ echo $_POST['movietitle'];}`
2: The part `unset($movie['title'])` will not delete the entire `$movie` object. Better use `unset($movie)`. This will delete the movie from the php Array (but not from the JSON!)

Comment: Oh I tried unset($movie) but no luck. I don't understand, delete from php array but not from JSON? So how can i delete it from JSON? 
I got file_get_content and json_decode already. So i guess i am already writing change to JSON file already right?

Comment: The JSON is a text file from which you can generate a PHP array. Unsetting parts of the array will discard parts of what you have read. But it does not modify the original data. You'd have to write to the JSON file to store the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the movietitle within apostophes

```
$title = $_POST['movietitle'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your json to php array like this:

```
$php_array = json_decode($json_value, true);
```

`$php_array` content:

```
[
   "abc" => [
        "title"=>"abc",
        "director"=>"ddd",
        "rating"=>"5",
        "subtitle"=>"Yes",
        "genre"=>"I",
        "category"=>"I",
        "release"=>"2018-05-03",
        "end"=>"2018-05-09",
        "link"=>"das",
        "synopsis"=>"dasdas"
    ],
    "afs" => [
        "title"=>"afs",
        "director"=>"fasf",
        "rating"=>"5",
        "subtitle"=>"Yes",
        "genre"=>"I",
        "category"=>"I",
        "release"=>"2018-05-09",
        "end"=>"2018-05-10",
        "link"=>"fsa",
        "synopsis"=>"fs"
    ]
]
```

Then unset the movie which is posted:

```
foreach($php_array as $movie=>$details){
   if($details['title'] == $_POST['movietitle']){
      unset($php_array[$movie]);
   }
}
```

And convert the result to json:

```
$json_output = json_encode($php_array);
```

Now, content of `$json_output` is the list of movies without `$_POST['movietitle']` in json format.